# Template function specialization vs. overloading

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, specialization, template-function

From some slides about template specialization:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class X> 
X& min(X& a, X& b)
{
    return a > b ? b : a;
}

int& min(int& a, int & b)
{
    // rewrite of the function in the case of int:
    cout << "int explicit function\n";
    return a > b ? b : a;
}

/* 
new syntax – the more appropriate way:
template<>
int& min<int>(int& a, int& b)
{
    cout << "int explicit function\n";
    return a > b ? b : a;
}
*/
```

Why is the second way more "appropriate"?

Comment: Relevant reading: [Why not specialize function templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Comment: Are these slides available online?

Comment: @Vaughn In a dropbox folder...

Comment: Remark: when declaring a template function specialization, you can use template argument deduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overload works fine for most of the contexts, and AFAIK is the suggested baseline approach. (see [GOTW](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) suggested by juanchopanza )

The difference hits if someone explicitly asks for the template, calling `min<int>(x, y)`. In that case overloads are ignored and only the template (base or specialized) are considered.

Comment: Also if someone uses the function from within another template.

Comment: @Daemin: Can you expand on what you mean?

Comment: In a function `template<typename T> T foo(const T& a, const T& b)` they call `min<T>(a, b);` hence it would use the templated version regardless of any non-templated overloads.